# Где можно увидеть лучшие работы по современной верстке?

Tags: css3, html5, flexbox, css-grid

Стоит задача хорошо прокачать `CSS-Grid` в комплекте с `FlexBox`.
После пройденных курсов по данному направлению появились некоторые вопросы и недопонимание относительно преимуществ данного подхода.
Вопрос:
Где можно увидеть работы с применением данных технологий - с учетом того, что бы каркас проектов использовался на гридах, а внутреннее содержимое было на флексах?
Буду благодарен за любые ссылки на корректные проекты(по данной тематике) с вашей точки зрения.

Comment: Вряд-ли что-то подобное найдется, лучше уж отдельно спросить про Ваши недопонимания

Comment: Ну тогда вопрос допустим такой:
Если мы создаем каркас на гридах делаем ему какое то количество колонок.
Далее внутренним элементам назначаем областя где эти елементы имеют право позиционироваться.
При изменении разрешения мы в таком случае что должны изменять ширину этих областей(в глобальном блоке) или их количество?
Если ширину - то чем это(фундаментально - с точки зрения подхода) отличается от того, если бы мы просто обычные блоки использовали и задавали им процентную ширину соответствующую разным разрешениям?

Comment: Всё правильно, можно и задавать им ширину, но подразумевается, что задать одно `grid` свойство с шириной всех колонок удобнее и легче читать, чем каждому блоку отдельно задавать ширину. Можно до сих пор верстать таблицами, просто речь идёт про более короткую запись

Comment: Удобнее всего пользоваться чем-то одним или Grid или Flex или Block и т.д